# Sftp Outbound gateway hangs after certain number of uploads

Tags: spring-integration

I am using sftp outbound gateway for transferring file to sftp. It hangs randomly after certain number of uploads. For example, say, I have 20 files to upload, It uploaded 10 files successfully and hangs and block all other process.

I am giving file to Sftp outbound gateway through a service activator.

My integration context  is as follows :

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway id= "sftpOutboundGateWay" command="put" expression="payload" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" 
    request-channel="sftpUploadChannel" reply-channel="sftpDataChannel" remote-directory="${sftp.dir}" />
```

The files in this gateway comes from service method. My method is like this :

```
public Message<?> provideFile(Message<?> masterData) {
    //some logic
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(fileObject).build();
}
```

Is the anyway to trace this issue or restart the outbound gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some component which doesn't return `reply`, hence a calling Thread is blocked for waiting for reply. Having such a vulnerability you end up with thread pool exhausting. Therefore the next task is just placed to the queue, but there is no Thread to perform that task.

You can try to investigate you issue from the Thread Dump.